# Usage of useRef as a React hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently learning React / Hooks, and I wonder what is the difference between these, if any:

```js
const [myRef, _dummy] = useState({current: 0});
const myRef = useRef(0);
```

(`_dummy` will never be used).

As I understand it, `myRef` can be used exactly the same way whatever the declaration we choose.

Is that true? If yes, is `useRef` simply a syntactic sugar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you've given, no, there is no difference

> If yes, is useRef simply a syntactic sugar?

No, there is a fundamental difference in that calling `_dummy` (i.e. setting the state) would cause a render where as setting the ref value would not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I said `useRef` was a syntactic sugar, I meant it does nothing more than what `useState` as declared above can do. So I understand you indeed confirm that?

Comment: And to be extra-clear, I meant that `useRef` could not exist and we still could emulate this functionality with `useState`

Comment: @Popov yes, `useRef` simply keeps track of the value across page renders which is the same as `useState` would do.

Answer (score 1):

They are not equivalent. When you update a state by calling setState you will trigger a rerender. However, when you update a ref, there will not be a rerender. This is because refs are intended to be mutable and not tied to the state of the component.

I'm assuming you are never going to change the value (as indicated by your dummy variable), in which case the two forms along with `const myRef = {}` are identical in practice but not semantically.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to change the value `myRef.current=...` directly, without using the `setXXX` function (`_dummy` in my example)

Comment: If you are asking about a specific use of useRef/useState, and not asking about the semantic differences between the two, you'll need to expand your example in your question before anyone can help.

Comment: Thanks, I think my question has been answered, I understand I can use `myRef.current` in both cases to get something like an "instance variable" for my function